# Error UiElement is not longer valid after publish process to UiPath Orchastrator

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-orchestrator

I created a robot on UiPath Studio and it were working well running at my machine.
Then I followed the steps to publish it at Orchestrator:

- I created a machine on Orchestrator(and linked the key license to the Uipath Assistant)
- I created a robot
- I created an environment
- I created a process linked to the robot

So when I run it from Orchestrator I got the error:

```
Process: IMPEXTRCOBR
Environment:
Robot: IMPEXTRCOB
Machine name: C205
Info: The UiElement is no longer valid
RemoteException wrapping UiPath.Core.InvalidUiElementException: O UiElement já não é válido ---> RemoteException wrapping System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040215
at UiPath.UiNodeClass.get_visibility()
at UiPath.Core.UiElement.IsVisible()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at UiPath.Core.Activities.ScopeActivity.OnFaulted(NativeActivityFaultContext faultContext, Exception propagatedException, ActivityInstance propagatedFrom)
at System.Activities.Runtime.FaultCallbackWrapper.Invoke(NativeActivityFaultContext faultContext, Exception propagatedException, ActivityInstance propagatedFrom)
at System.Activities.Runtime.FaultCallbackWrapper.FaultWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
Start Time: 04/24/2020 11:16:22 AM
End Time: 04/24/2020 11:16:29 AM
Input Values: null
Output Values: Empty
Has Recording: false
```

And now If I try to run it from my machine I got the same error. And if I try to "fix" the selector of the activity I got the error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you delete the activity and add that again by plain?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to give us a screenshot of your [UiPath Sequence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iGU3Lzzv8wg) project?

Typically these errors occur when a selector is too specific and information that might change, like a page title, is included.

### Inherited properties

Often properties in a selector are inherited. So a [UiPath scraping](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPpEUSp1AwY) activity might be getting its title property from an Attach Browser activity from which it is connected. In that case, the ability to delete the title in the attached activity will be disabled. You'd have to go to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem like you,
when I used the click method
I have gotten through this problem by changing the method **using Click Image Activity** instead of Click Activity.

[image]

This can solve common click errors of not using any selectors to click on specific UI elements.
maybe far from your expectations but this method can help.